# Make Xml with toprettyxml

Tags: python, xml

I use `Python` to create an `XML` File.
My code is :

```
rough_string = ET.tostring(CanDef, 'utf-8') #CanDef is my main Element
reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
XmlFile = reparsed.toprettyxml()
```

And what I get with this code is :

```
<CanDef>
  <CanDB>
    <Msg CallBack="NULL" Can="0" DLC="3" Dir="tx" ID="273" MsgName="Frm0x111">
        <Signal Can="0" Dir="tx" Len="8" Max="1" Min="-1" MsgName="Frm0x111" Offset="1" Pos="1" Reso="127.5" SigName="myCos"/>
        <Signal Can="0" Dir="tx" Len="8" Max="1" Min="-1" MsgName="Frm0x111" Offset="1" Pos="2" Reso="127.5" SigName="mySin"/>
        <Signal Can="0" Dir="tx" Len="8" Max="255" Min="0" MsgName="Frm0x111" Offset="0" Pos="3" Reso="1" SigName="myAdd"/>
    </Msg>
</CanDB>
```

And what I want to have is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<CanDef>
    <CanDB>
        <Msg
          Can="0" 
          MsgName="Frm0x111"
          ID="273"
          Dir="tx"
          DLC="3"
          CallBack="NULL"
        >
            <Signal
                Can="0"
                MsgName="Frm0x111"
                Dir="tx"
                SigName="MyCos"
                Pos="1"
                Len="8"
                Min="-1"
                Max="1"
                Offset="1"
                Reso="127.5"
            />
            <Signal
                Can="0"
                MsgName="Frm0x111"
                Dir="tx"
                SigName="MySin"
                Pos="2"
                Len="8"
                Min="-1"
                Max="1"
                Offset="1"
                Reso="127.5"
            />
            <Signal
                Can="0"
                MsgName="Frm0x111"
                Dir="tx"
                SigName="MyAdd"
                Pos="3"
                Len="8"
                Min="0"
                Max="255"
                Offset="0"
                Reso="1"
            />
        </Msg>
</CanDef>
</CanDB>
```

Is it possible to get the second solution using `toprettyxml`?
Because I found something about `indent` and `newl`(newLine) but it looks like the first solution evry time even if I change indent and newl arguments...

Best Regards
Ka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported by toprettyxml function, but you can achive what you want with this function:

```
import re

def toevenprettierxml(xml, indent = '  ', newl = '\n'):
   for ind, element in re.findall(r'^(\s*)(\<\w+\s+.+\>)', xml, re.MULTILINE):
      even_prettier_element = re.sub(r'\s+', newl + ind + indent, element)
      even_prettier_element = re.sub(r'(/?\>)', newl + ind + r'\1', even_prettier_element)
      xml = xml.replace(element, even_prettier_element)
   return xml
```

You will get exactly what you need.

Another option, if the xml format is not set, is to replace attributes with elements, e.g.:

```
<Msg>
  <Can>0</Can>
  <MsgName>Frm0x111</MsgName>
  ...
</Msg>
```